# Android TableLayout isn't displaying rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having problems getting my TableLayout to display my rows.

I'm propagating the rows programmatically via this method:

```
private void buildStatesTable() {
    Log.d(SelectStatesPanel.class.getCanonicalName(), "Entering Build States Table");
    ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if(i < goodStates.length){
            states.add(goodStates[i]);
        }else{
            states.add(badStates[rand.nextInt(badStates.length)]);
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(states);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.statesTable);
    final int NUM_PER_ROW = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < (states.size() / NUM_PER_ROW); i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getContext());
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for(int j = 0; j < NUM_PER_ROW && (i*NUM_PER_ROW + j) < states.size(); j++){
            TextView lblState = new TextView(getContext());
            lblState.setText(states.get(i*NUM_PER_ROW + j));
            lblState.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            lblState.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lblState.setClickable(true);
            lblState.setOnClickListener(this);
            tr.addView(lblState);

            //Log.d(SelectStatesPanel.class.getCanonicalName(), "Adding State: " + states.get(i*NUM_PER_ROW + j));
            Log.d(SelectStatesPanel.class.getCanonicalName(), "\t\t\t (" + i + ", " + j + ")");
        }

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr);
        Log.d(SelectStatesPanel.class.getCanonicalName(), "Adding Row");
    }
}
```

And this is my XML (table layout is at the bottom):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:text="Good choice! There's hope for you yet."
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLex"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:text="Lexington"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTampa"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:text="Tampa"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSacramento"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:text="Sacramento"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHiltonhead"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:text="Hiltonhead"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/usa"
        />
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"        
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/statesTable"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1">        
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Why isn't my table layout's showing content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem on my own.

The problem was this:

```
        lblState.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Specifying TableRow.LayoutParams fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see specifically what is going wrong in your code, but here is a similar implementation in my own code:

```
public class EconFragment extends Fragment {


    private TableLayout questionContainer;
    static int pos = 0;
    private String[] titles = {"The first title ", "hallo1","hallo2", "hallo3",
            "hallo4", "hallo5","hallo6", "hallo7","hallo8", "hallo9"};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Econ", "onCreateView");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        questionContainer = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questionContainer);



        //these lines are my first attempt to try and get the questions to repopulate after returning
        //from pressing back - as of yet, they don't repopulate the screen:
        //View econFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.econfragment, null);
        //container.addView(econFragment);

        int leftMargin=5;
        int topMargin=5;
        int rightMargin=5;
        int bottomMargin=5;
        while (pos < 10) {
        View question = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);
        question.setId(pos);
        TextView title = (TextView) question.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
        title.setText(titles[pos]);
        Button charts = (Button) question.findViewById(R.id.chartsButton);
        charts.setId(pos);
        charts.setOnClickListener(chartsListener);
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) question;
        TableLayout.LayoutParams trParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        trParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trParams);

        questionContainer.addView(tr);
        pos++;
        }
        Log.d("Econ", "onResume");
    }
```

And the source of questionContainer, econfragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/questionContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

As you can see, a Question.class object is created as a View object in the EconFragment fragment. question object is used to findViewById for each needed portion.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the whole row code and replace it with a two liner textview row. Does that work? Then the array from which you build your row views is maybe the problem.
Best regards.

Comment: That made no difference. And rows added in the XML appear. So I have no idea what's going on.